# Ocaml function, what is the nature of the problem?

Tags: function, recursion, printing, ocaml

Currently i'm trying

I have a function to calculate the inverse sum of a number

```
let inverseSum n =
  let rec sI n acc =
    match n with
    | 1 -> acc
    | _ -> sI (n - 1) ((1.0 /. float n) +. acc)
  in sI n 1.0;;
```

For example, `inverseSum 2` -> 1/2 + 1 = 3/2 = 1.5

I try to test the function with 2 and 5, it's okay:

```
inverseSum 2;;
inverseSum 5;;

inverseSum 2;;
- : float = 1.5
inverseSum 5;;
- : float = 2.28333333333333321
```

For the moment, no problem.

After that, I initialize a list which contains all numbers between 1 and 10000 ([1;…;10000])

```
let initList = List.init 10000 (fun n -> n + 1);;
```

no problem.

I code a function so that an element of the list becomes the inverse sum of the element
(e.g. `[1;2;3]` -> `[inverseSum 1; inverseSum 2; inverseSum 3]`)

```
let rec invSumLst lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | h::t -> (inverseSum h) :: invSumLst t;;
```

and I use it on the list `initList`:

```
let invInit = invSumLst initList;;
```

So far so good, but I start to have doubts from this stage:

I select the elements of invList strictly inferior to 5.0

```
let listLess5 = List.filter (fun n -> n < 5.0) invInit;;
```

And I realize the sum of these elements using fold_left:

```
let foldLess5 = List.fold_left (+.) 0.0 listLess5;;
```

I redo the last two steps with floats greater than or equal to 5.0

```
let moreEg5 = List.filter (fun n -> n >= 5.0) invInit;;
let foldMore5 = List.fold_left (+.) 0.0 moreEg5;;
```

Finally, I sum all the numbers of the list:

```
let foldInvInit = List.fold_left (+.) 0.0 invInit;;
```

but at the end when I try to calculate the absolute error between the numbers less than 5, those greater than 5 and all the elements of the list, the result is surprising:

```
Float.abs ((foldLess5 +. foldMore5) -. foldInvInit);;
Printf.printf "%f\n" (Float.abs ((foldLess5 +. foldMore5) -. foldInvInit));;
Printf.printf "%b\n" ((foldLess5+.foldMore5) = foldInvInit);;
```

returns:

```
let foldMore5 = List.fold_left (+.) 0.0 moreEg5;;
val foldMore5 : float = 87553.6762998474733
let foldInvInit = List.fold_left (+.) 0.0 invInit;;
val foldInvInit : float = 87885.8479664799379
Float.abs ((foldLess5 +. foldMore5) -. foldInvInit);;
- : float = 1.45519152283668518e-11
Printf.printf "%f\n" (Float.abs ((foldLess5 +. foldMore5) -. foldInvInit));;
0.000000
- : unit = ()
Printf.printf "%b\n" ((foldLess5+.foldMore5) = foldInvInit);;
false
- : unit = ()
```

it's probably a rounding problem, but I would like to know where exactly the error comes from?

Because here I am using an interpreter, so I see the error "1.45519152283668518e-11"

But if I used a compiler like ocamlpro, I would just get 0.000000 and false on the terminal and I wouldn't understand anything.

So I would just like to know if the problem comes from one of the functions of the code, or from a rounding made by the `Printf.printf` function which wrote the result with a "non scientific" notation.

Comment: The problem with printing is that it will round up the float, so if `a-.b` is small enough but `a<>b`, you might still get `0.000000` when printing `a-.b`, and it's actually what happens.

Comment: Try printing with higher precision: `%.20f` or in exponential notation `%e` or using `string_of_float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCaml is showing you the actual results of the operations you performed. The difference between the two sums is caused by the finite precision of floating values.

When adding up a list of large-ish numbers, by the time you reach the end of the list the number is large enough that the lowest-order bits of the new values simply can't be represented. But when adding a list of small-ish numbers, fewer bits are lost.

A system that shows `foldLess5 +. foldMore5` as equal to `foldInvInit` is most likely lying to you for your convenience.